# CORS AJAX-request fails even though the correct headers are specified

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, apache, cors

I am trying to send an AJAX-request from a page hosted on Github Pages (with https) to a php script hosted on a different domain (also https).

This is the code I am using in my AngularJS controller (although I don't think that is the problem):

```
$http.get('//thorin.epizy.com/cors.php?url=Place%2FGetClosestPlacesExtension%3Fcoordinates%3Dx%3D'+Math.round(vm.coords[0])+'%2Cy%3D'+Math.round(vm.coords[1])+'%26proposals%3D12').success(function (data) {
  vm.success = true;
  console.log('Recieved data from Ruter:',data);
});
```

The request fails and gives this error in the console:
[image: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://thorin.epizy.com/cors.php?url=Place%2FGetClosestPlacesExtension%3Fcoordinates%3Dx%3D600593%2Cy%3D6646876%26proposals%3D12. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://tjespe.github.io' is therefore not allowed access.]

When opening the `Network` panel in Chrome I see that the CORS headers are not present:
[image]

However, when I visit the page directly in the browser (typing the url into the url field) and open the `Network` panel all the correct headers are present:
[image]

I have tried sending the request from pages on other domains as well, bu I get the same error and no CORS headers. This makes very little sense to me and I have no idea how to fix it. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a strange reason, `thorin.epizy.com/cors.php` doesn't send CORS headers without cookies:

```
curl -I 'http://thorin.epizy.com/cors.php?[...]' <other headers>
Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 16:42:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 920
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

With cookies, we get the correct headers:

```
curl -I -H 'Cookie: __test=b142b58439ba4f78e04c32cd1ba0a991' 'http://thorin.epizy.com/cors.php?[...]' <other headers> 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 16:45:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 16:45:04 GMT
```

When you do a cross site request and want cookies, you need to ask for them with [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) ([`withCredentials: true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) with angularjs).

Then, the server will need to [change two things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials):

- add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in the response
- change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-web-site.com` (usually taken from the `Origin` request header)

If you don't you will get the following message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://thorin.epizy.com/cors.php?url=[...]’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

Comment: Wow, thanks for looking so thoroughly into it! I will change my code and see if it works.